# SQL query from html form with multiple optional inputs

Tags: sql, forms

If I have a form on a page that has multiple optional inputs: inventory number, Date, building, manufacturer, etc.  How can I make it so the SQL query that happens when submit is pressed, functions based on what is filled in on the form.   IE. If they only pick a building and click submit, it returns just that buildings information, but if they pick a building and a date, the same submit button still works.  Basically, have the query work with the single submit button no matter what combination is used.  They will only be returning results, not inputting data into the database with the form.

The query below is what I use to return all results and display them.  The included form is currently non-functional, I just included it in hopes it helps.

```
<form action="dblog.html" id="frmMain" method="post" name="frmMain">
Building:
<select name="building" id="building">
            ~[tlist_sql;SELECT DISTINCT location_id, location_description FROM u_locations ORDER BY location_description]
                <option value="~(location_id)" >~(location_description) </option>
            [/tlist_sql]
            </select><p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Start Date: 
<input type="text" name="startdate" id="datetimepicker2"/><p>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;End Date:
    <input type="text" name="enddate" id="datetimepicker5"/><p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inventory Number: 
    <input type="text" name="Inventory Number" id="invnum"/><p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Manufacturer: 
    <input type="text" name="Manufacturer" id="manfac"/><p>
<input name="btnSubmit" value="Continue" type="submit">
</form>



<div class="box-round">

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
<td class="bold">#</td>
<td class="bold">Inv Number</td>
<td class="bold">Date</td>
<td class="bold">PO</td>
<td class="bold">PO Date</td>
<td class="bold">Cost</td>
<td class="bold">Model</td>
<td class="bold">Vendor</td>
<td class="bold">Location</td>
</tr>

~[tlist_sql;
SELECT
uc.inventory_number,
uc.date_inventoried,
uc.po_number,
upo.po_date,
upoli.cost,
udesc.model,
uv.vendor_name,
uloc.location_description
from u_computers uc
left outer join u_departments ud on uc.department_id = ud.department_id
left outer join u_description udesc on uc.description_id = udesc.description_id
left outer join u_locations uloc on uc.location_id = uloc.location_id
left outer join u_po upo on uc.po_number = upo.po_number
left outer join u_po_line_item upoli on upo.po_number = upoli.po_number
left outer join u_vendors uv on uc.vendor_id = uv.vendor_id
order by uc.inventory_number ASC;alternatecolor]
<tr bgcolor="#edf3fe">
<td>~(count;-)</td>
<td>~(uc.inventory_number;t)</td>
<td>~(uc.date_inventoried;d)</td>
<td>~(uc.po_number;t)</td>
<td>~(upo.po_date;d)</td>
<td>~(dupoli.cost;t)</td>
<td>~(udesc.model;t)</td>
<td>~(uv.vendor_name;t)</td>
<td>~(uloc.location_description;t)</td>

</tr>
[/tlist_sql]
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly; Declaring the values passed to the SQL statement with values not set being defined as **null**, and checking each input value for **null** as part of the WHERE clause, will return the results as described.

An example of how this could be achieved using a stored procedure is below, however this should be able to be translated to meet your needs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <owner>.<procedure name>

    @inventory_number INT = null,
    @date DATETIME = null,
    @building NVARCHAR(50) = null,
    @manufacturer NVARCHAR(50) = null

AS

    SELECT DISTINCT name, location, floors
    FROM buildings
    WHERE (inventory_number = @inventory_number OR @inventory_number = null)
    AND ([Date] = @date OR @date = null)
    AND (building = @building OR @building = null)
    AND (manufacturer = @manufacturer OR @manufacturer = null);
```

I hope this helps.